# Ошибка в функции | C++

Tags: c++

```
int framed_area(int x,int y)
{
    const int frame_width=2;
    if (x-frame_width<=0||y-frame_width<=0)
    {
        error("non-positive area() argument called by framed area");
    }
    return area(x-frame_width,y-frame_width);
}
```

Если у меня есть эта функция в моей программе, я получаю сообщение "'error' was not declared in this scope".  Какую библиотеку следует включить, чтобы мой код работал правильно?

Answer (score 0):

У вас компилятор к моменту компиляции кода не встретил объявления функции `error()` - возможно, вы не включили соответствующий заголовочный файл, или объявляете его в тексте ниже.

Что касается замечания @Duracell об именах - то, по всей видимости, он не совсем разобрался в вашем коде. Все остальное у вас корректно, если, конечно, определена функция `area()`.

Условие

```
x-frame_width<=0||y-frame_width<=0
```

вполне корректно, так как приоритет вычитыния выше сравнения, а тот, в свою очередь, выше приоритета оператора ИЛИ.

P.S. Где-то я этот код видел - в какой-то книжке... Не Страуструп, "Принципы программирования"? Если да - то, насколько я помню, он там все свои функции засунул в один заголовочный файл. Вы его включаете в свой текст?..

Comment: исправил, не доглядел код, на счет условия - то его можно записать короче

Comment: @Duracell Вы бы уж отвечали там, где разговор начался, а то непосвященному непонятно, на что вы отвечаете. По сути - вы имеете в виду сэкономить четыре символа и написать `x<=frame_width||y<=frame_width`? Можно, но это не делает исходную запись некорректной. Меняется ли удобочитаемость и понятность - тут спорить не стану, скорее дело вкуса.